# UIImagePickerController's cameraOverlayView is offset after taking photo

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, cameraoverlayview

When you implement a `cameraOverlayView` for a `UIImagePickerController`, this view appears while you're taking the photo and after the photo has been taken, providing you with an opportunity to cancel or retake the photo. The problem I'm seeing is if your `cameraOverlayView` is on top of the photo preview area, when you take the photo and it shows you the preview, the photo you took doesn't align with the `cameraOverlayView` anymore. The entire photo preview pane has been moved down ~50 points while the `cameraOverlayView` has stayed in place. This is a problem when you need the photo to be aligned perfectly with the view.

How can this be adjusted so the two are perfectly aligned - while taking the photo and after it has been taken?

Notice how the whole preview area is pushed down after taking the photo.

[image]

Comment: I'm struggling with just the same problem and have already asked the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/30329523/1492708

Did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: @BogdanWeidmann I did not, I ultimately had to resort to doing everything myself via AVFoundation.

Comment: Hi Joey, have you been able to implement also Photo Library photo picking functionality? Would you be so kind to share the steps and some code, how you've achieved this? I appreciate your time! :)

Comment: Looks like an Apple bug. I filed a radar, you might want to dupe it: http://www.openradar.me/30513073

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and came up with the following workaround:

```
if (IPhone5 || IPhone5c || IPhone5s)
{
     imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(imagePicker.cameraViewTransform, 0, 30);
}
else if (IPhone6 || IPhone6Plus)
{
     imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(imagePicker.cameraViewTransform, 0, 44);
}
```

This ensures that the picture that was taken will have approximately the same center as the camera preview layer (in portrait orientation).

Comment: this kind of work, but photo quality is altered. I have an OCR behind that is not working if I transforme camera view. :(